# System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException

Tags: vb.net

This error is generated in a ratio of 5:1.  4 times it will work without error, but the next time it runs it will return the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" for the same query string.

My system uses a web service (SVC) to connect to a MySql database for all of its CRUD operations. The Error is listed below:

> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: DELETE FROM
>   customer_number WHERE cus_id =4 Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object. at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage
>   message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean
>   asyncCall)    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String
>   methodName, Object[] parameters) at 
>   POS.ThePOSServerService.PosMain.ExecuteQueryBool(String strQuery,
>   String Company, String User, String Pass) in Reference.vb:line 266

While the code that generates error is as follows with line numbers:

    `Try
    261  Dim ConnectionString As String = _ 
           ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings(Company).ConnectionString
    262  'Dim sCommand As StringBuilder = New 262 - StringBuilder(strQuery)
    263  Using mConnection As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection(ConnectionString)
    264      mConnection.Open()
    265      Using myCmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(strQuery, mConnection)
    266          myCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    267          Result = myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0
    268      End Using
    269  End Using`
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New ApplicationException(ex.ToString)
    End Try

I just want to get Result to be True or False to return as a value.

Comment: Error correction. The Row number is 266.

Comment: It seems that line 267 referes to your local Reference.vb file containing the proxy ExecuteQueryBool function on the client side. Add Try/Catch around server side code to see and log what's going on there.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply.
But I have already covered this entire code in Try/Catch and that's how I got this error description.
I need to create it without any error. and it is line 266. Thanks

Comment: No one can answer or what? :) I am really in trouble. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It is my fault. never checked that the connection string was correctly coming into the function. once I corrected that (giving the correct connection string) everything went as I was expecting. Thanks to all anyway.